# mysqli_multi_query database class error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am sure of this that this question hasn't asked anywhere even on the blog of creator of this class.

since morning i have started using php database class of [bennettstone](https://github.com/bennettstone/simple-mysqli). I was trying to add **MYSQLI_MULTI_QUERY** into this class to handle multiple queries at once.

till now, I have been able to modify up to below extent. But it is not working. I am extremely poor with classes & this is my first attempt ever !!

I am getting error at two lines & don't know how i will access the result set of multiple queries. let's say 3 queries.

**1) Error at while statement And similar error at mysqli_free_result statement**

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given on line 352
```

Request some help:

```
public function multi_select_query( $query )
{
    $i = 0; 
    $row = array();
    $query = $this->link->multi_query( $query );

    if ( mysqli_error( $this->link ) ) {
        $this->log_db_errors( mysqli_error( $this->link ), $query, 'Fatal' );
        return false;
    } else {                
        do {    
            $i ++;  
            $result[$i] = mysqli_store_result($this->link); 

            while ( $r = mysqli_fetch_array( $query, MYSQLI_ASSOC )) {
                $row[$i][] = $r;
            }

            mysqli_free_result( $query );                                     

         } while ( $this->link->more_results() && $this->link->next_result() );

        return $row[$i]; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Stop mixing OO and procedural mysqli versions.

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_array( $query, MYSQLI_ASSOC )` - $query is a `bool` because that is what is returned from multi_query() - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: @u_mulder - As i stated, this is my first attempt & i tried to use existing setup to done the desired.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I made it myself somehow.

Below is the final working class example which can be easily accessed by foreach loop using following statement.

$result = $dbc->multi_select_query($query);

```
public function multi_select_query( $query )
{
    $row = array();
    $i = 0;             

    $query = $this->link->multi_query( $query );
    if( mysqli_error( $this->link ) ){
        $this->log_db_errors( mysqli_error( $this->link ), $query, 'Fatal' );
        return false;
    } else {    
         do{                    
            $i ++;
            if($result[$i] = $this->link->store_result()) 
            {
                while ($r[$i] = $result[$i]->fetch_row())
                {
                    $row[$i][] = $r[$i];
                }
                $result[$i]->free();                                    
            }                                   

         } while( $this->link->more_results() && $this->link->next_result() );

        return $row; 
    }
}
```